# mysql two tables with the same structure - want to get one common field ordered by via a union

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables that have the same structure, I need a query to order by from both tables at the same time so that the array fetched with php grabs the order correctly out of the two tables selected with a single query at the same time.

avoiding selection of each table separately, storing on php arrays and then sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), it should be just like you would think. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from 
(select * from tbl1
union all
select * from tbl2
) a
order by col1
```